# how to ask permission for 2 useStates with useEffect

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, use-effect

I want to ask permission for both camera and camera_roll. Once I added the code for camera_roll permission the camera permission no longer ran.

```
const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
const [rollPermision, setRollPermission] = useState(null);
```

```
 useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      getpermission()
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
      // camera roll
      const { cam_roll } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      setRollPermission(cam_roll === "granted");
    }
    )();
  }, []);
```

and if the permission has failed...believe I have too many if statements here but I don't know how else to do it

```
  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text style={styles.text}>No access to camera</Text>;
  }
  if (rollPermision === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (rollPermision === false) {
    return <Text style={styles.text}>Need access to camera roll</Text>;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The useReducer hook seems like a better option there. Think you'll create more elegant API with it.

Comment: reading on useReducer right now but more confused on how this would still go. The initialState would be null, then I would have 2 reducers (one for camera and one for camera_roll) and then I would have a useEffect that would call each one of those reducers?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to improve your UX would be:

```js
const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(false);
const [rollPermision, setRollPermission] = useState(false);
```

I think the Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL is only necessary for iOS.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      getpermission()
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
      // camera roll
      if (Constants.platform.ios) {
        const { cam_roll } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        setRollPermission(cam_roll === "granted");
      } else {
        setRollPermission(true);
      }
    }
    )();
  }, []);
```

```
if (!hasPemission || !rollPermision) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.text}>To acess the camera, yoou need:</Text>
      {!hasPermission && (
        <TouchableHighlight onClick={handleAskPemission('CAMERA')>
         <Text style={styles.text}>Camera Roll permission</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      )}
      {!rollPermision && Constants.platform.ios && (
        <TouchableHighlight onClick={handleAskPemission('CAMERA_ROLL')>
         <Text style={styles.text}>Camera Roll permission</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}

  return <CameraView />
```

Comment: could you please explain `handleAskPemission("Camera_roll")` a little to me? Would that be a function that is set to handleAskPemission that would equal to setting hasPermission to `true`?

Comment: @BruceMathers Yes, you could extract that permissions questions from the `useEffect ` to be possible for the user gives permission touching the button